# Python List count() returns nothing instead of 0

Tags: python, count

I am trying to get the count of elements in a nested list after iterating over it. However, when the element i'm looking for is not in the list, I want the code to return me `0`. But it gives me a blank output instead of `0`.How can I solve it?

```
s=[['F1','S1'],['F2','S2'],['F3','S3'],['F1','S2'],['F2','S3'],['F3','S2'],['F2','S1'],['F4','S1'],['F4','S3'],['F5','S1']]
F=[]
S=[]
for a,b in s:
    F.append(a)
    S.append(b)
for i in s:
    if i[0]=='F1' and i[1]=='S1':
        print('P(F=F1|S==S1):',s.count(i),'/',S.count('S1'))
    if i[0]=='F1' and i[1]=='S2':
        print('P(F=F1|S==S2):',s.count(i),'/',S.count('S2'))
    if i[0]=='F1' and i[1]=='S3':
        print('P(F=F1|S==S3):',s.count(i),'/',S.count('S3'))
```

the output I get is :

```
P(F=F1|S==S1): 1 / 4
P(F=F1|S==S2): 1 / 3
```

I don't getout put when `i[0]=='F1'` and `i[1]=='S3'` .

Comment: your `i` contains whole `[F1, S1]` not separate items of sublist.

Comment: There are no cases in this input where `i[0] == 'F1'` and `i[1] == 'S3'`. Was there supposed to be such a case?

Comment: Why are you iterating over `s` at all? Why the `if`s?

Answer (score 0):

Your list does not contain a pair for F1 and S3

Answer (score 0):

If you're counting things you might want to look at `collections.Counter`:

```py
from collections import Counter
s =[['F1','S1'],['F2','S2'],['F3','S3'],['F1','S2'],['F2','S3'],['F3','S2'],['F2','S1'],['F4','S1'],['F4','S3'],['F5','S1']]
​
Counter(tuple(i) for i in s)
```

Result:

```
Counter({('F1', 'S1'): 1,
         ('F2', 'S2'): 1,
         ('F3', 'S3'): 1,
         ('F1', 'S2'): 1,
         ('F2', 'S3'): 1,
         ('F3', 'S2'): 1,
         ('F2', 'S1'): 1,
         ('F4', 'S1'): 1,
         ('F4', 'S3'): 1,
         ('F5', 'S1'): 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your list doesn't contain a [f1, s3].
Next time try to debug it using print statements, so print out each iteration in the terminal

Answer (score 0):

You don't get the output because the if condition isn't satisfied.              If you'll print the i[0] and i[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Gfcg.png) values in every iteration, you'll realise that the values are as follows:

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you, Jil. The intended output when [F1,S3] is not in the list is :       
 'P(F=F1|S==S3): 0 / 3'. Is there a way to implement that?

Comment: Can you please elaborate? From what I understand, you want to implement the third if condition when i[0] is not equal to F1 and i[1] is not equal to S3? If that's the case, just change your last if condition as follow:  `if i[0]!='F1' and i[1]!='S3':` Hope it helps!